# Cloudify python script plugin - how to use packages?

Tags: python, cloudify

I am trying to run a python script on cloudify and for that I am using the script plugin.
Now I've managed to get the script running but it fails when importing the python packages it needs.
Is there a way to install those packages in cloudify manager's python environment?. My blueprint looks like this:

```
tosca_definitions_version: cloudify_dsl_1_3

imports:
    - http://www.getcloudify.org/spec/cloudify/5.0.0/types.yaml

inputs:
    input1:
        description: description1
    input2:
        description: description2
        type: string

node_templates:
    node_name:
        type: cloudify.nodes.SoftwareComponent
        interfaces:
            cloudify.interfaces.lifecycle:
                start:
                    implementation: scripts/python_script.py
                    executor: central_deployment_agent
                    inputs:
                        input1: { get_input: input1 }
                        input2: { get_input: input2 }
```

the imports I need are at the beggining of python_script.py:

```
import ssh
import bottle
import paramiko
```

ssh is a file I wrote in the scripts folder I uploaded to cloudify as part of the blueprint package.
Cloudify is not finding ssh and I don't know how to make sure that bottle and paramiko are installed on cloudify

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install anything into the worker environment manually.
I assume that you are trying to execute some SSH commands on a remote machine.
I would propose the following...
**Option 1**
Use the ready terminal plugin [Terminal plugin](https://github.com/cloudify-incubator/cloudify-utilities-plugin/tree/master/cloudify_terminal)
Here is an example [Terminal plugin example](https://github.com/cloudify-incubator/cloudify-utilities-plugin/blob/master/cloudify_terminal/examples/linux-ssh.yaml)

**Option 2**
Build a wagon archive with all dependencies and upload it to Cloudify Manager as a plugin.

1. you can use the template [Plugin template](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-plugin-template)
2. populate the plugin code and dependencies in setup.py
3. build wagon
4. upload it to the manager

To build a wagon you need to have docker installed:

1. Build docker from a ready Dockerfile [Docker files for Wagon builder](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-wagon-build-containers) .
   You need to choose OS that matches the one that Cloudify is running. Cloudify 5.1 uses Python 3.6 so centos_7_py3 would be a default option. py2py3 builders will provide Python 2.7 and 3.6 compatible plugins that can work on new and old Cloudify versions.
2. Run Docker and provide it a directory where the plugin source is - it will build a wgn file
   It is all described in the README.md [Wagon builders readme](https://github.com/cloudify-cosmo/cloudify-wagon-build-containers)